# Probability of repairing a TV Set

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A town contains $4$ people who repair televisions. If $4$ sets break down, what is the probability that exactly $2$ of the repairers are called?
Soln: What i have tried is " ${4 \choose 2}/4^4$, but its wrong."
Can someone help me with the concept in this question ?

Comment: You have to add a bunch of assumptions, such as: all $4$ sets belong to different families; each family with a broken set will call one and only one repairer; the probability of calling each repairer is equal, and the calls are independant of each other; etc. Most importantly, the title should be "repairing $4$ TV sets"...

Comment: Yes the assumptions are all 4 TV sets are different and all 4 repairers are differet.

Answer (score -1):

An approach is  to count the number of winning samples.

The total number of possibilities is equal to $4^4$, as a given family has 4 possibilities for selecting a repairer.

Let us first count the number of possibilities, for a given pair $(A, B)$ of repairers to be selected and only then.

Then, repairer $A$ can be selected by:

- 1 family -> ${4 \choose 1} = 4$ possibilities
- 2 families -> ${4 \choose 2}$ possibilities
- 3 families -> ${4 \choose 3}$ = 4 possibilities

Once $A$ is selected by a given set of families, there is only one possibility for $B$ to be selected by all the other families. For example, if $A$ is selected by families $F1$ and $F2$, $B$ is selected by families $F3$ and $F4$.

So total number of possibilites for $(A, B)$ to be selected by all families is equal to $4 + {4 \choose 2} + 4$

As there are ${4 \choose 2}$ possibilities to select a pair of repairers, then the total number of events with two repairers selected is

$$ N = {4 \choose 2} \left(4 + {4 \choose 2} + 4\right) = 84$$

Finally the corresponding probability is equal to

$$ P = \frac{ {4 \choose 2} (4 + {4 \choose 2} + 4)}{4^4} = \frac{21}{64} $$

Comment: The answer after solving this is coming out to be 27/128 which is incorrect.

Comment: So you know the correct answer ? Which is ?

Comment: The correct answer is 84/256 which is simplified when the following expression is solved
4C2(4+4C2+ 4), which  i am unable to figure out.

Comment: The above is a solution in Sheldon Ross, first course in probability.

Comment: Note that my solution does not give $27/128$ but something more complex. What is $C_2$ ?

Comment: It means 4Combination2 choosing 2 from 4, i am not able to figure how to put the correct format for Combination symbol thats why i have simple form of 4C2

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand where there is an error in my answer, and I can't see where your formula comes from. For the moment, I let my answer, someone else could indicate where there is an error, in this case I will delete my answer. If I find something myself, I will modify it.

Comment: So the correct answer is 4C2(4+4C2+4)/4^4. I forgot to divide it by 4^4 which is the sample space.

Comment: Corrected. Good solution this time ... (I hope)

Comment: yes this is the correct soln

Comment: Please don't forget to accept this solution if it helps you

Comment: I am unable to understand it thats the only point.

Comment: What is unclear ?

Comment: how is (4+4C2+4) coming up ?

Comment: I sum up the cases corresponding to *A selected at least once, but not by all*. Once A is selected by some families, B must be selected by all remaining families, which does not increase the number of samples.